# R has {drake} which makes it easy to make reproducible data pipelines. Does Python have a similar package?

Tags: python, r, pipelines

See [R's {drake}](https://github.com/ropensci/drake). It allows you to define a reproducible pipeline

```r
plan <- drake_plan(
  raw_data = readxl::read_excel(file_in("raw_data.xlsx")),
  data = raw_data %>%
    mutate(Species = forcats::fct_inorder(Species)),
  hist = create_plot(data),
  fit = lm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width + Species, data),
  report = rmarkdown::render(
    knitr_in("report.Rmd"),
    output_file = file_out("report.html"),
    quiet = TRUE
  )
)

# call the pipeline
make(plan)
```

The great thing about drake is you that you can reload any of `raw_data`, `data`, `hist`, `fit`, `report` at any point. And if you change part of the code and `make(plan)` and {drake} will figure out which has change and just run that.

Comment: I see a contributor with a similar name for this project. Are you advertising your project here? Is this not against the rules?

Comment: Wow! I am asking for a Python equivalent cos I want to do the same. Also, u saw that I only made one contribution which was minor. Also the author of drake included disk.frame which was one of my package

Comment: The question is still open. Can you accept my answer? If its not satisfactory you can comment and I can try to help you more^^

Answer (score 3):

`Sklearn` has pipeline. If you have `fit` and `transform` attributes iteratively, you can make them pipeline by `Pipeline` class in `sklearn.pipeline`.

Read the docs:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html

Additionally you can save and load a pipeline object by `joblib.dump` and `joblib.load`.

Comment: it's not the same as drake at all

Answer (score 2):

For larger projects [snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a way to go for Python (it extends Python syntax, valid Python is valid snakemake). It originates in bioinformatics and even has its own [publication](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/28/19/2520/290322/); it is widley adopted and used by many projects (see the literature list in the first link or the citations for the linked article).

For Jupyter notebook based projects, I made an experiment called [nbpipeline](https://github.com/krassowski/nbpipeline) which you may be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Ploomber works the same way, it keeps track of your source code and it only runs outdated steps to bring your pipeline up-to-date: https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber

Disclaimer: I'm the project's author